# need eyes on a (to me) tricky sql

Tags: mysql

In a mysql db, I have two tables:

**prices** - iid, trade_date, price

**trades** - iid, trade_date, nominal, price

I am trying to create an aggregated, cumulative series with the dates from prices and the values calculated as sum(trades.nominal*prices.price) but nothing comes out the way I want.

[SQL Fiddle 1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a799b6/3)

[SQL Fiddle 2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d4a6d3/3)

This is what I want to achieve:

[image]

Any help greatly appreciated!

PS. Had a typo. It said value = trades.nominal * trades.prices...it should be trades.nominal * prices.price.

Comment: Incidentally, price is rarely double; it's why decimal was invented

Comment: Here's a result somewhat similar to your own. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a799b6/17

Comment: Yes, it is close, but not exactly what I'm after. I'm not entirely sure what your result show...it's not trades.nominal * prices.price

Comment: Brilliant Strawberry!!! I just had to make 2 small adjustments and it gave me exactly what I was looking for [SQL Fiddle Solution](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a799b6/48)

Comment: I suggest you post what you have as an answer. And then 'accept' that.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this, but I'm not using the price in the `trades` table.

```
select
    t1.trade_date,
    t1.iid,
    sum(t1.nominal * p1.price) as total
from
    trades t1
    inner join prices p1 on t1.iid=p1.iid AND t1.trade_date = p1.trade_date
group by t1.iid, t1.trade_date
order by t1.trade_date;
```

Can you explain which prices have to be used? The prices are currently redundant.

Comment: The prices are from the price table.

Answer (score 0):

Strawberry gave an almost perfect answer, thx.

[Solution](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a799b6/48)